# How parse quasi-html text in java?

Tags: java, parsing

The quasi html text, looks like:
`Simple<br> text <b>simple</b> text simple <BR><BR>text simple text`, I would like to parse it and create [dom document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html). But problem is with **unclosed tags**, when I try this:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(
Document doc = builder.parse(source);
```

Error occurs: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;  The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag`

I don't want replace all `<br>` by `<br></br>`, any solution or advice?

Comment: You probably can't get it into a DOM. You need to use a lenient HTML parser like [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) - it will try and fix the HTML as it goes. A bit like a web browser would.

Comment: I think it can be done with HTMLEditorKit...

Comment: @BoristheSpider no need for the jSoup it can be done with standard Java, see my answer.

Comment: This is pretty hard in the general case -- you might need to copy code from web browsers to get it working decently, and you'll always have some error rate.

Comment: @Mehrdad I agree. In the case there is a lot of different data, I'd go with jSoup. I just don't like dependencies unless they are really necessary :)

Comment: It's too much chemistry getting the DomDocument out of HTMLEditorKit solution. I deleted my answer and upovted the jSoup solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and enjoy the ease of use.

Answer (score 3):

You must rewrite all well formed HTML. Basically you go through the text and create a List of all opening tags. When you find a corresponding closing tag, you can remove it from the list. When you are through, and you still have entries in this List, you know its not well formed.

The problem is where to insert the unclosed Tags. You can try to insert a corresponding closing tag, right after the next word. In your case you can simply replace the br tag by br / tag, if thats the only occurence. This way string represntes the document's content.

```
string = string.replace("<br>", "<br />");
```